# Best way to hide constexpr calculations

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, constexpr

I would like to create a constexpr param struct. Several of its members would be calculated by constexpr functions.
Like:

```
class Params {
public:
    static constexpr size_t featureWinW{ 7 };
    static constexpr size_t featureWinH{ 7 };

private:
    static constexpr size_t getKernelSize()
    {
        //complex calculation
        return 20;
    }

public:
    static constexpr size_t kernelSize{ getKernelSize() };
}
```

I know that getKernelSize is like it were defined outside the class, so the code is wrong:

```
error: ‘static constexpr size_t Params::getKernelSize()’ called in a constant expression before its definition is complete
```

How should I reformat my code to be valid without spamming even a dedicated namespace with private-like calc functions?

Comment: You should be putting your code into its own namespace.  You can then add an alias to the global space for the class if you really want to.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. By 'global' I mean the application namespace. Yes, I could move it to another namespace, but I do not want it to be reachable anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda usage might be considered:

```
class Params {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t featureWinW{ 7 };
    static constexpr std::size_t featureWinH{ 7 };
    static constexpr std::size_t kernelSize{
        [](){
            //complex calculation
            return 20;
        }(); //  immediately called.
     };
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/mm884y)

Comment: Whoa, this is exactly what I need :) The code compiles even when the lambda uses public or private members. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fERDCM) Is it intended, enabling to access private members seems to be a bit strange for me. It is a great solution anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might consider a friend helper class:

```
class ParamsHelper {
    friend class Params; // friend declaration + forward class declaration
    static constexpr int getKernelSize()
    {
        //complex calculation
        return 20;
    }
};

class Params {
public:
    static constexpr int featureWinW{ 7 };
    static constexpr int featureWinH{ 7 };

    static constexpr int kernelSize{ ParamsHelper::getKernelSize() };
};
```

Comment: It was my first idea, but I hope I can avoid it somehow. ParamsHelper (the class itself) would be still accessible even with friends as you described. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In C++, there are a number of things you want to keep "hidden" for internal use, but you cannot reasonably use `static` class members to do. The standard idiom for handling these things is to create a namespace named `detail` or something similar to stick them in. You should use this idiom here.

C++20 modules may give us a more effective means for labeling data for internal use, but until then, the detail namespace is the best that can be done.